# TextViews become single-line instead of multi-line when populated in a thread

Tags: android

I have an Activity that retrieves information from a url. I have 2 textviews which are multi-line (txtTitle & txtContent). If I populate them without using thread, it displays as multi-line. However, when I use a thread, the text views become single-line.

Is there anything I'm missing? Is the UI not completely ready when I tried putting text in it?

## My sample code is below:

package com.mysite.app;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.text.Html;
import android.text.Spanned;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ViewNewsActivity extends Activity implements Runnable{

```
private ProgressDialog progressDialog = null; 
private String apiUrl = "";
private String title = "";
private String content = "";
private Runnable viewNews;
private TextView txtTitle = null;
private TextView txtContent = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.view_news);

    Intent myIntent = getIntent();
    apiUrl = "http://www.mysite.com" + myIntent.getStringExtra("api_url");



    Thread thread =  new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(ViewNewsActivity.this,    
            "Please wait...", "Retrieving News ...", true);

}


public void run() {

    txtTitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.view_news_title);
    txtContent = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.view_news_content);
    getNews(apiUrl);
    handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);

}


private Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        txtTitle.setText(title);
        Spanned contentHtml = Html.fromHtml(content);
        txtContent.setText(contentHtml.toString());
    }
};

private void getNews(String apiUrl) {
    String result = JSONUtils.getJSONResponse(apiUrl);

    JSONObject jsonResponse;
    try {
        jsonResponse = new JSONObject(result);
        title = jsonResponse.getString("title");
        content = jsonResponse.getString("content");


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: implementing runnable on an Activity class seems like an extremely bad idea

Comment: I wasn't using Runnable on the Activity before but I decided to try it if it makes a difference. I still have the same issue implementing Runnable or not.